# Enforce a lower-bounds that "excludes" a super type

Tags: scala, typing, type-bounds

Bounds in Scala allow more granular control of types in Scala, for example argument types.
For example

```
def foo[ S <: String ]( arg: S ): S = ...
```

The above allows a function to accept arguments that are sub types of String, also

```
def bar[ S >: A <: B ]( arg: S ): S = ...
```

The above allows the setting of an upper and lower bound so that S is a sub type of B and a super type of A.

My question is (I assume the bounds are inclusive) would it be possible to set up an argument type so that the argument would be a supertype of say String, but not include some super type of the lower bound (in this case String) say type Any.

**UPDATE**

```
sealed trait Helper[S]
object Helper {
  implicit def stringSubtype[S >: String] = new Helper[S]{}
  implicit def any = new Helper[Any]{}
}

def foo[S: Helper](r: S): Int = 1

val arg1: String = "hi"
val arg2: Any    = "hello"

foo(arg1)
foo(arg2)
```

I would expect that the call with arg2 should result in an illegal argument exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more complex type constraints like this you can do type-level programming via implicits:

```
sealed trait Helper[S]
object Helper {
  implicit def stringSubtype[S >: String] = new Helper[S]{}
  implicit def any = new Helper[Any]{}
  implicit def any2 = new Helper[Any]{}
}

def foo[S: Helper] = ...
```

`foo` can only be invoked with a type `S` for which an implicit `Helper[S]` can be resolved. `stringSubtype` supplies a `Helper[S]` for any `S >: String`. But for `Any`, both that and `any` apply and the two implicits conflict, so it's not possible (well, except by explicitly passing one or the other) to call `foo[Any]`.

Update: it seems that `any` is somehow higher priority than `stringSubtype`, so it's resolved for `foo[Any]`. Rather than figure out exactly why this is, the simplest workaround was to also define `any2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried using it but I'm unable to archieve the desired results. Please take a look at the update I added to the question.

Comment: Just commenting that the update to the answer seems to address the update in the question :). I will note that the mystery remains for why exactly `any2` remains as of scala 2.12.2 (and in dotty: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bbarker/VRGskOyrRyaRKWIOeJ8FUA/1).